# Reason behind ScriptManager.GetCurrent method

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

Asp.net team had designed script manager such that only one instance existed per page(HttpHandler), i can't find a valid reason why they had extended a method like [`ScriptManager.GetCurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.getcurrent.aspx) to get the instance inside a page. Why couldn't developers do

```
if(ScriptManager == null)
{
    throw new Exception("The Below ajax control requires ScriptManager in the page");
}
```

Comment: I guess ScriptManager is the ID of the ScriptManager control, right? You do not have the access to the id from a user control, when the ScriptManager is on the MasterPage.

Comment: @slfan sorry i hadn't put down the scenario here. Be it any asp file(usercontrol,masterpage,child page, nested masterpage). Asp.net team(kudos guys keep improving) had devised a way to recognize ScriptManager instance in the page but didn't they set the `Current` ScriptManager class in the request/response to that one in the page(which might have a ID like sManager,resourceManager etc) something like i know i can get the username of person logged in using `User.Identity.Name` when memebership is enabled. I am kind of getting feeling that this is purely conventional, decision made for future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe because there might be other places than the code behind file of the page to access the actual ScriptManager. With the static method GetCurrent() you can access the ScriptManager of the current context from anywhere in the code (e.g. from a class library). The implementation of GetCurrent looks like this:

```
public static ScriptManager GetCurrent(Page page)
{
    if (page == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("page");
    }
    return page.Items[typeof(ScriptManager)] as ScriptManager;
}
```

Therefore it's just a shortcut to get access to the ScriptManager instance.

Your code would not work from a content page or a user control, when the ScriptManager is defined on the master page.

Comment: what do you mean by >other places than the code behind there is `HttpContext.Current` right onto which `request` and `response` are present(which means script manager too)

Comment: true, but it's a shortcut. I added the implementation of GetCurrent